# Multiplos DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, html-helpers

Depois de pesquisar bastante na documentação e verificar aqui mesmo no StackOverflow, decidi perguntar.

Minha questão é a seguinte eu criei dois DropDownList.

View como está agora:

```
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("TradeItems", String.Empty)

        &nbsp;
        @Html.DropDownList("CoinItems", String.Empty)

        &nbsp;
    </div>
```

Já mandei os dados da lista que criei por meio do controller e estou tentando recuperar os valores selecionados.

Meu Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(int? value, int? value2)
    {
        Junction junction = new Junction();

        ViewBag.TradeItems = junction.FirstItems.ToList();
        ViewBag.CoinItems = junction.SecondItems.ToList();


        if (value != null)
        {


            switch (Convert.ToInt32(value))
            {
                case 1:
                    apiCall.getName1(1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    apiCall.getName1(2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    apiCall.getName1(3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    apiCall.getName1(4);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    apiCall.getName1(5);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    apiCall.getName1(6);
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (value2 != null)
        {


            switch (Convert.ToInt32(value2))
            {
                case 1:
                    apiCall.getName2(1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    apiCall.getName2(2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    apiCall.getName2(3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    apiCall.getName2(4);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    apiCall.getName2(5);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    apiCall.getName2(6);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Tentei desta forma mas não deu certo para os dois DropDownList.

View como estava antes:

```
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("TradeItems", null, 
            new { onchange = "document.location.href='/Home/Index?value=' + this.value; " })
        &nbsp;
        @Html.DropDownList("CoinItems", null, 
            new { onchange = "document.location.href='/Home/Index?value2=' + this.value2; " })
    </div>
```

Alguma ideia de como posso recuperar os valores das duas seleções separadamente ?

Comment: só uma dica, no lugar do `switch` não poderia ser `apiCall.getName1(Convert.ToInt32(value2))`? melhor usar uma variável, mas só pra exemplificar. Sobre a pergunta, pq não passa `this.value` nos dois, e passa um outro parametro dizendo de qual dropdown vem o valor?

Comment: E ao invés do location.href... o ideal é você utilizar uma requisição ajax. E estude um pouco mais sobre o asp.net, mvc e web api